# Can I determine how the Flashback trojan infected my machine despite disabling Java?

Tags: java, malware

Apple's update on April 17, 2012 detected and deactivated the Flashback trojan.

Yet two weeks ago I had following the instructions [here](http://www.f-secure.com/v-descs/trojan-downloader_osx_flashback_i.shtml). After concluding that my Mac is not infected, I disabled Java.

I don't understand how Flashback could have sneaked in, especially after my guard has been up after an [Arstechnica article](http://arstechnica.com/apple/news/2012/04/mac-trojan-exploits-unpatched-java-vulnerability-no-password-needed.ars), but that no longer matters.

How do I find out what kind of damage might have already been done? Will one of the log files contain a trace of what has happened?

Comment: There may have been different version of Flashback than the one in the F-secure instructions. Did you disable Java in all browsers that you were using or in Java Preferences (in Utilities)?

Comment: Only in the browsers (Safari + Firefox), but I see that Java is also disabled in Java Preferences, which the last Apple patch said would do.

Answer (score 1):

I'd be surprised if the logs told you anything useful.

If you're concerned, you could install one of the [free AV](http://www.sophos.com/en-us/products/free-tools/sophos-antivirus-for-mac-home-edition.aspx) products for the Mac. Do a full system scan to ensure that all traces of the trojan have been removed.